# Facebook graph api reach

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I'm trying to get reach using the graph api for the previous 7 days.
For this I used

```
me/insights?metric=page_impressions_unique&period=day&since=1462924800&until=1463529600
```

The problem is that the total reach returned by the above url **is not equal** with the reach displayed on the facebook website/ insights tab(please see the fig1 for more details).
Using the api I get Reach **2293**, BUT facebook displays **494** people reached, for the same period of time.

I'm thinking that maybe i'm not using the same metric as facebook does, maybe they are displaying the reach per post and not per page, but this is only my theory.

Can you please help me out to determine the same value as facebook does?

[image]

Thanks,
Catalin

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with you query. You're querying for the metrics on yourself. Replace 'me' with the page id.

```
<page_id>/insights?metric=page_impressions_unique&period=day&since=1462924800&until=1463529600
```